# NSScreen was autoreleased during loadNib()

Tags: cocoa, autorelease

I am OSX developer. The problem I encountered is described as below:

```
- (void)method1:(NSObject *)arg1
       contextInfo:(NSObject *)arg2
{
   ...
   [self method2:arg1
             screen:[self.windowController window].screen];
   ...
}

- (void)method2:(NSObject *)arg1
            screen:(NSScreen *)screen
{
   ...
   MyWindowController *myWindowController =
      [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];
   NSWindow *aWindow = [MyWindowController window];   // A Problem happens
   ...
}
```

After executed the line "A Problem happens", I found that the content of the screen (that is, the *screen) changed.

```
(gdb) p *screen
$15 = {
  <NSObject> = {
    isa = 0x7fff788a6598        xxxxxxxx changed
  }, 
  members of NSScreen: 
  _frame = {
    origin = {
      x = -4353346,              xxxxxxx changed
      y = -234234
    }, 
    size = {
      width = -35252435,             xxxxxxxx changed
      height = -3452663,              xxxxxxxx changed
    }
  }, 
  _depth = 520, 
  _screenNumber = 2077752383, 
  _auxiliaryStorage = 0x0
}
```

At the very beginning, I thought there could have been a stack overflow or memory corruption that resulted in this issue. But then I used gdb to watch the when *screen is changed. And I also thought that perhaps due to a memory corruption, screen has been released unexpectedly. So I also rwatched the screen and *screen. But what I got is only that:

(Please forgive me to have changed some log because I cannot release parts of the code here.)

```
#0 0x00007fff8427824f in objc_msgSend () 
#1 0x00007fff8c5748e4 in -[NSScreen dealloc] () 
#2 0x00007fff8581528a in CFRelease () 
#3 0x00007fff85852efc in -[__NSArrayI dealloc] () 
#4 0x00007fff8427c230 in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop () 
#5 0x00007fff8583cd72 in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop () 
#6 0x00007fff8c07c172 in loadNib () 
#7 0x00007fff8c07b88c in +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] () 
#8 0x00007fff8c1ce5bc in +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] () 
#9 0x00007fff8c20160b in -[NSWindowController loadWindow] () 
#10 0x00007fff8c2012e5 in -[NSWindowController window] () 
#11 0x000000010003c3c9 in -[SessionListener method2:screen:] (self=0x10220caa0, _cmd=0x100261922, arg1=0x10209ede0, screen=0x1020b7d20) at SessionListener.m:307 
#12 0x000000010003d3f4 in -[SessionListener method1:contextInfo:] (self=0x10220caa0, _cmd=0x1002618a0, arg1=0x10206b950, arg2=0x0) at SessionListener.m:457
```

The rwatch and watch were set at the very beginning of the method2 being executed.
Then I got the first break while executing the "A Problem happens"line with above stack trace.

From my observing, the loading of the window seemed to trigger an Autorelease cycle that released the NSScreen.
But I didn't do anything like autoreleasepool drain or release. So I wondered why it happened that way.

The last thing is that, this issues doesn't always happen. It is very easy to reproduce this issue on my 13 and 15 inch retina MBPs(OSX 10.8.2) but cannot repro on my other 13 inch MBP non-retina (OSX10.8.2).

Could any one leave a comment?

Thanks